# Can't run slapd inside an ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, openldap, containers, slapd

I am trying to create two docker containers, one to act as an ldap server and the other an ldap client. I started by creating the server. I am running on ubuntu 18.04 and using ubuntu image for my container, I just installed slapd & ldap-utils but when I try to run "/etc/init.d/slapd" start or to run it manually with "slapd" it just exits without giving any output. I looked into this issue for a long time, I don't know anything about ldap but in all the tutorials I went through no one mentioned any extra steps to run slapd.

I used the -d option to get debug logs and I can't find anything wrong, but since I barely know anything about ldap I thought someone here might be able to help.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18L0dTuk3HdlZB3b4-DipSB9yDOKbuZ08/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include your slapd configuration and logs in your question. Without them, no one here can help you. You did include a link to the logs, but pasting them into the question makes it easy for people to see them, and makes your question still useful when the linked content goes away.

Comment: I will add my config once I get home, but for the logs it was too big to include as text in my question, I tried. If there's a workaround for this let me know

Comment: It's fine to include just the part of the logs that seem relevant.